# Purchase a physical scrumboard?

Tags: scrum, agile, team-management, planning

Any ideas on where to acquire a pre-drawn physical scrumboard? I want to save the hassle of preparing one and to just buy it somewhere. If there are nice boards like that would also look professional and stylish I would definitely get one.

Any ideas? Was anyone interested in this before?

Thanks, 
Tim

Comment: Purchasing questions are off topic.

Comment: Doesn't sounds very agile to me - what happens when you decide to change your process?

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic almost everywhere on the SE network. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ for details.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you'll find a pre-created scrum board.  A pre-made scrum board would be a pretty niche market for a manufacturer to target.

It gets more complicated though. Different teams have different workflows and thus need different numbers of columns (looking around at the 4 team boards I can see at the moment I see teams with 3, 5, 6 and 8 columns).  This would mean that in order to maximise sales to an already small market, you'd have to produce a variety of column options.

To make matters worse, on most boards I've used we have swim lanes for different types of work or themes and some columns may not require as much vertical space so you might get two workflow steps in one column.

With so many permutations, you'd probably have to build them to order otherwise you'd be tying up lots of cash in stock.

That said, it is possible to buy pre-gridded boards which might help?  (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Ultralon-Gridded-Whiteboard/dp/B00G9FTVTG)

Otherwise, invest in some gridding tape, a set square and a spirit level :D
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Nobo-Self-Adhesive-Gridding-Black/dp/B000J6F4NI

Answer (score 0):

When I did this for a few teams, I bought really large magnetic white boards (the high quality kind that don't suffer from marker burn-in)  I believe these were 12ft x 5ft (3.5m x 1.5m).  You can then also purchase either electrical tape (comes in colors) or "chart tape" (which can create much thinner lines)  Then you can lay out your board as you want.  Neither tape leaves a residue, so easy with 10 min of work to change the layout.  The magnetic nature of the board is great in general as well.

Note: We also had "movable" whiteboards that could be unhung, moved to a different conference room then rehung.  For those, we created things like a "risk board" where we drew in permanent marker on those boards for the background then in dry-erase for the variable data this worked well and the Sharpie will actually come off (draw over with dry erase, then wipe off) but since these layouts didn't change much, we were okay with the permanent nature of the board.

Note: This is an "expensive" option.  I think the magnetic whiteboards were $850 each (we bought one for each team) and the movable were about the same, but much smaller (figure 3-4 for each team)
Note2: This lasted about 6 months where the managers were "doing everything by hand" to become familiar with the process.  After a few months they knew the process well enough to know what to look for in a tool.  Then, we went SW and never looked back.

ymmv